# node.js child process exit but executed program still running

Tags: c++, node.js, child-process

I use child_process.exec() api to execute a C++ problem with timeout option:

`child_process.exec('main.exe', {timeout: 1000}, callback)`

After timeout, the child_process call the callback function with error, but when I try to run `child_process.exec('main.cpp', {timeout: 1000}, callback)` again, I received error say that main.exe still running.

How can I stop main.exe after timeout?

following is main.cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use Node,js  process.kill(), and ChildProcess.kill() [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12378) ?

Comment: I try childProcess.kill(), not working. process.kill() need pid as parameter, but child process and main.exe has different pid.